# MySQL LocalDate is being passed as String in JPA Native Query

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, spring-data-jpa, mysql-workbench

I am passing a LocalDate in a JPA native query. But it is taking it as String and executing.

I get a different result when I execute the same query in MySql Workbench and from Java using the native query.

- In MySQL Workbench:

  ```sql
  select sum(expense_amount) from budgetreferee.br_expense 
  where household_id=1 and next_due_date between 2018-08-01 and 2019-07-31 
    and category_id IN(41,51,58,70,74,83,94,2,20,10,9,22,28) OR 
      is_bill=TRUE and expense_id IS NOT NULL;
  ```

  The result is: 58171.00
- Using the native query:

  ```java
  @Query(value = "select sum(expense_amount) from br_expense where household_id=:householdId and next_due_date between str_to_date(:startDate,'%Y-%m-%d') and str_to_date(:endDate,'%Y-%m-%d') and category_id IN(41,51,58,70,74,83,94,2,20,10,9,22,28) OR is_bill=TRUE and expense_id IS NOT NULL;",nativeQuery = true)
  BigDecimal getTotalExpenseAmount(@Param("householdId") Long householdId, @Param("startDate") LocalDate startDate, @Param("endDate") LocalDate endDate)
  ```

  That results in this query:

  ```sql
  select sum(expense_amount) from budgetreferee.br_expense 
  where household_id=1 and next_due_date between str_to_date
   ('2018-08-01','%Y- %m-%d') 
     and str_to_date('2019-07-31','%Y-%m-%d') and 
      category_id IN(41,51,58,70,74,83,94,2,20,10,9,22,28) OR is_bill=TRUE 
    and expense_id IS NOT NULL;
  ```

  The result is 109871.00

How can I resolve this discrepancy?
I want 58171.00 to be the output when I execute it from Java.

Answer (score 0):

JPA 2.1 was released before Java 8, and that is the reason why LocalDate is not supported by default. You could use a `Converter` to do the job for you.

```
import java.sql.Date;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import javax.persistence.Converter;

 @Converter(autoApply = true)
 public class LocalDateAttributeConverter implements AttributeConverter<LocalDate, Date> {

  @Override
  public Date convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDate localDate) {
      return (localDate == null ? null : Date.valueOf(localDate));
  }

  @Override
  public LocalDate convertToEntityAttribute(Date sqlDate) {
      return (sqlDate == null ? null : sqlDate.toLocalDate());
  }
```

}